# Cannot access remote MySQL from apache through SSH

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ssh

Problem:
Cannot access remote MySQL from apache through SSH

My goal is to access DB from APP server securely using apache and tomcat through ssh tunnel.
APP server (Linux) is running apache httpd, tomcat.
DB server (Linux) is running mysql server (port 3306).
SSH is setup for user: sshUser on both servers. MySQL on DB is started.

SSH connection:
On APP server, I ran the following as sshUser. (sshUser is a login user of both APP and DB server)

```
ssh -p 22 -f -N -L 3307:localhost:3306 sshUser@DB_ip_address
```

then I started httpd and tomcat on APP server.

Test cases:
1. APP server (httpd) (localhost:3307)>(3306) DB server (MySQL) failed:
on APP server, in apache, I run test.php as the following php code

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost:3307"; 
$db_name = "dbname"; 
$db_user = "dbuser"; 
$db_pass = "dbpassword"; 
GLOBAL $errors; 
GLOBAL $successes;
$errors = array(); 
$successes = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
GLOBAL $mysqli;
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Conn Error = " . mysqli_connect_error();    exit();
}else{
    echo "Pass";    exit();
}
?>
```

error message:
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3307' (1) in /$site_path/test.php on line 10, Conn Error = Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3307' (1) 
(using joomla and wordpress also failed)

2. APP server (tomcat) (localhost:3307)>(3306) DB server (MySQL) is good:
3. windows 8 (httpd) (localhost:3307)>(3307) APP server (3307)>(3306) DB server (MySQL) is good:
   On windows 8 client, the putty destination is APP server,  SSH tunnel set forwarded port 3307 (source port) localhost:3307 (destination).
   If I run the same test.php from my apache server on windows 8.1, it has no problem. Joomla also works. (the configuration is as following)
4. windows 8 (tomcat) (localhost:3307)>(3307) APP server (3307)>(3306) DB server (MySQL) is good:

Configuration detail:
on APP server:
Tomcat is started by “tomcat” user 
httpd is started by “apache” user 
mysqld is started by “root”
ssh is started by “sshUser”
sshd is started by “root”

in /etc/passwd  (same on APP server and DB server)
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
tomcat:x:501:501::/home/tomcat:/sbin/nologin

Comment: This question is probably best suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: $db_host="localhost:3307" works in windows8,not in Linux. Since joomla has no port parameter,I change to default port. new problem: I have a Mysql running on  APP server. I change it to 3309. then ssh -f -N -L 3306:localhost:3306 sshUser@DB_IP. But joomla always goes to the Mysql at local, which is 3309. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html "For connections to localhost, MySQL using a Unix socket file, even if a --port is given a port number." I change to , ssh -p 22 -f -N -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 sshUser@DB_IP_address. in php, change $db_host="127.0.0.1" to make it work.

Comment: I cannot change the question myself. But this does related to programming. The code needs to work around for joomla and mysql features which are very subtle. (described in my previous comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to  add port number as parameter to constructor

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_port=3307;
.....
new mysqli ( ....,$db_port);
....
```

Comment: Thanks. That is it. The original format "localhost:3307" actually works on windows 8. But not on Linux. Now my problem is in joomla, it doesn't provide a separated parameter for port. I guess I need to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost:3307` is not a valid host name.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

> ```
> mysqli::__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")
> [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd
> = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket =
> ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> **host**
>
> Can be either a host name or an IP address. (...)
>
> (...)
>
> **port**
>
> Specifies the port number to attempt to connect to the MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks. That is it. The original format "localhost:3307" actually works on windows 8. But not on Linux. Now my problem is in joomla, it doesn't provide a separated parameter for port. I guess I need to ask another question.